# R.oo package won't install on RStudio Server

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm perplexed that the R.oo package installation fails on RStudio server, any idea on how I can get around it?

```
Installing package(s) into ‘/home/rstudio/R/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://ftp.heanet.ie/mirrors/cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/R.oo_1.9.3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 372217 bytes (363 Kb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 363 Kb

* installing *source* package ‘R.oo’ ...
** package ‘R.oo’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in match(el, set, 0L) : object 'R.KEYWORDS' not found
Error : unable to load R code in package ‘R.oo’
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘R.oo’
* removing ‘/home/rstudio/R/library/R.oo’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘R.oo’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: I *just* had the same problem but it’s unrelated (at least here) to RStudio: I tried installing it on a conventional R installation, same error.

Comment: I actually didn't have a problem installing it on my local copy of RStudio -- it went fine there, it's just the server version that's having a problem for me.

Comment: I don't have a linux box here to try it out, but the Rstudio support mentions this is a linux issue: http://support.rstudio.org/help/discussions/problems/2696-roo-does-not-install-on-rstudio-server

Comment: Yes, I actually posted that on the RStudio support forum under a different handle.  I have a Linux box, so that makes sense.  I'm going to ping the package maintainer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the author of the R.oo and R.KEYWORDS packages, there was an incompatibility between the last version of R.KEYWORDS (v1.4.2) and R.oo (the cran version 1.9.3 was incompatible, not being the last one v1.9.8). He corrected that recently.

Answer (score 1):

As of last night: I can confirm this problem on two different RStudio servers, one running R.2.14.1, the other R.2.15.1, so it's not R version. One is our linux server, the other is an amazon EC2 server. And no problem installing on a local RStudio (OSX; R.2.15.0).

HOWEVER:  as of an hour ago, this problem has disappeared. On both RStudio Servers, R.oo now installs fine.  So, try again!